# Is there a way to parse yaml field that can be array of string or single String using SnakeYaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm currently using SnakeYAML lib to parse yaml. Everything is fine except the fact that i have fields that can sometimes be String or sometimes array of Strings as follows:

```
fields:
  amount: NET A PAYER (-?[\d ]+,\d{2})
  amount_untaxed: TOTAL HT ([\d ]+,\d{2})
  amount_tva: TOTAL TVA ([\d ]+,\d{2})
```

and with arrays:

```
fields:
  amount: TotalincludingVAT£(\d+\.\d+)
  date:
    - Invoicedate(\d{1,2}\w+,\d{4})
    - Issuedate(\d{1,2}\w+,\d{4})
```

so how can i make something that can handle fields containing single string and fields containing arrays ? I'm currently using a Map >String,String> to store fields but it doesnt handle fields that are arrays. I tried a Map>String, List>String>> to handle this but this doesnt work for single strings.

Comment: Use `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Yes it's what I've done thanks for your answer